# Using variables from the same js file in 2 html files with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get my variable I have saved to display on a table I have created on another page. I get the information from the user from a form, and have a button that is clicked and fires off to save the values into variables. My problem is that I can't change the inner html on the other page with the variable I have saved. I am using 1 js file and 2 html files. I can only use js/jquery, html, and css. here is my code:

**loanpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Super Awesome Loan Guys</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loanpage.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loanpage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg" id="text-center">
        <div class="companytitle"><span class="dollar">$</span>uper Awe<span class="dollar">$</span>ome Loan Guy<span class="dollar">$</span></div>
        <div>
            <form action="infopage.html">
                <h4>Loan Amount:</h4>
                <input type="text" id="loanamount" name="loanamount"><br>
                <input type="radio" id="12month" name="time">12 Months
                <input type="radio" id="18month" name="time">18 Months
                <input type="radio" id="24month" name="time">24 Months
                <h4>Name:</h4><input id="namefield" type="text" name="firstlastname">
                <h4>Phone:</h4><input id="phonefield" type="text" name="phonennumber">
                <h4>Email:</h4><input id="emailfield" type="text" name="email">
                <h4>Zip Code:</h4><input id="zipfield" type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
            </form>
            <a href="infopage.html"><button type="button">Submit</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**infopage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Super Awesome Loan Guys Loan Information</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loanpage.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loanpage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg" id="text-center">
        <h1>Here is the info you submitted!</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Zip Code</th>
                <th>Loan Amount</th>
                <th>Loan Duration</th>
                <th>Interest</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="displayName">1</td>
                <td id="displayPhone">1</td>
                <td id="displayEmail">1</td>
                <td id="displayZip">1</td>
                <td id="displayAmount">1</td>
                <td id="displayDuration">1</td>
                <td id="displayInterest">1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**loanpage.js**

```
//js code
var name = "";
var phone="";
var email="";
var zip="";
var loan=0;
var loanrate=12.0;
var loanlen=0;
//Jquery code
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
       loan = parseFloat($("#loanamount").val());
    if ($("#12month").is(':checked')){
        loanlen = 12;
    }
    else if ($("#18month").is(':checked')){
        loanlen = 18;
    }
    else if ($("#24month").is(':checked')){
        loanlen = 24;
    }
    name = $("#namefield").val();
    phone = $("#phonefield").val();
    email = $("#emailfield").val();
    zip = $("#zipfield").val();
    document.getElementById("displayName").innerHTML(name);
    document.getElementById("displayPhone").innerHTML(phone);
    document.getElementById("displayEmail").innerHTML(email);
    document.getElementById("displayZip").innerHTML(zip);
    document.getElementById("displayAmount").innerHTML(loan);
    document.getElementById("displayDuration").innerHTML(loanlen);
    document.getElementById("displayInterest").innerHTML(loanrate);
});
```

});

Comment: Are the pages open simultaneously?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a set-state by default, so variables set on one page won't be available in another page, unless they're transferred to that page, either via GET or POST-variables, localStorage or by having both pages open in the same browser simultaneously (or loading the second page via iframe or ajax).

Comment: Your best solution here is by using localStorage

Comment: @Jersh I don't think so. I am supposed to click the submit button and be taken to the info page, and I need access to those variable in the js file to change the inner html of the info page

Comment: As previously stated look into localStorage. Beware of browser support.

Comment: Ok, so after looking at localStorage and trying to add it to my c9 project, it says the localStorage is no defined. Do I need to add anything to make it defined? And also, how would I use it between pages? Would I keep it in the ready function?

Answer (score 2):

Local Storage is your best bet.

```
// Save data to the current local store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Access some stored data
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: After looking at it, I am not sure how to really use it, and c9 says that localStorage is undefined

Comment: Hmm.. I tried the code in a jsfiddle, it works fine. Check your browser compatibility? Also, what's your code look like?